# What is the precise explanation of box-shadow and -moz-box-shadow in CSS?

Tags: shadow, dropshadow, css

I find the explanations of CSS's `box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadown` somewhat imprecise.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-background-20100612/#the-box-shadow

> The third length is a blur distance.
> Negative values are not allowed. If
> the blur value is zero, the shadow's
> edge is sharp. Otherwise, the larger
> the value, the more the shadow's edge
> is blurred.
>
> The fourth
> length is a spread distance. Positive
> values cause the shadow shape to
> expand in all directions by the
> specified radius. Negative values
> cause the shadow shape to contract.

Is it true that the fourth length will use the same color (the darkest shade), and repeat that for the specified width?  So it won't be smoothly blurring out?

Can it achieving specifying the rate of blurring or the rate of fading out...?

Does someone know very precisely how they exactly work?

Answer (score 4):

Well, imagine that the box shadow starts as a box, the same size as the content, of the specified shadow colour (say black for argument's sake).

This box starts life the same size and shape as the content, and right behind it - so, essentially, invisible.

The two *distance* values will shift it up, down, left or right - so that it will "peek" out from behind the content. At this point, it will still be a box of the same size as its content, and will have sharp edges.

The *spread* value will cause this box to expand by the specified amount - so it will be *bigger* or *smaller* than its content box. Visually, the higher the spread, the further "back" the shadow appears (it gives the illusion that the box is a long way away from the surface that it's casting its shadow on).

The blur value simply causes the edges to blur smoothly into the background, fading from the shadow colour to the background colour.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a web/CSS programmer, but I needed a box-shadow algorithm that looked like CSS's, and decided to find out how it works.

I used CSSmatic's [online box-shadow tool](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) for the comparisons below.

The algorithm seems to have 2 steps.

## Step 1: Vectorized scale and shift

[image]

As shown, a `27px` CSS spread *inset* means the shape is scaled to have dimensions `27*2` pixels *smaller*. This is inverted for outline box-shadows (e.g. `27*2` pixels *larger*).

The horizontal/vertical offsets are self-explanatory.

## Step 2: Gaussian blur

### History

Mozilla developer David Baron wrote a detailed article on CSS box-shadow implementations [here](https://dbaron.org/log/20110225-blur-radius).

Up until 2011, there was no standard meaning for the CSS blur radius. It could correspond to different algorithms *and* parameters in different web browsers:

> Different browsers ... have historically done different things
>   for the same blur radius, both in terms of blurring algorithm and what
>   the radius means for that algorithm (i.e., how blurry a given radius
>   makes things). .... Over the past year, the CSS and HTML specifications
>   have changed (for CSS) to define what this blur radius means or (for
>   HTML) so that they agree with each other on this definition.

Those historic differences could explain the purpose of the `moz-` prefix (which you mentioned) and `webkit-` prefix. These likely specify alternative box-shadow parameters for Mozilla and [WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css)-based browsers to use.

I expect these prefixed versions are now deprecated, due to standardization, but may be used for compatibility with older browsers.

### Standardization

According to Baron there is now a *precise, standard definition* of the box-shadow blur radius:

> The blur effect is now defined by css3-background and by HTML to be a
>   **Gaussian** blur with the **standard deviation (σ) equal to *half* the given blur radius**, with allowance for reasonable approximation error.

A mathematician could expand that into an exact formula.

### Visual approximation

With some trial-and-error in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), I found that a Gaussian blur radius obtained by multiplying the CSS blur parameter by 5/3 (1.6666...), then rounding up to the nearest integer, produces a very close visual approximation (to CSS in Firefox 50):

`7px` CSS blur (Firefox 50) ~~ `ceil(7 * 5/3.0) = 12.0` Gaussian radius in GIMP

[image]
[image]

`30px` CSS blur (Firefox 50) ~~ `ceil(30 * 5/3.0) = 50.0` Gaussian radius in GIMP

[image]
[image]

`75px` CSS blur (Firefox 50) ~~ `ceil(75 * 5/3.0) = 125.0` Gaussian radius in GIMP

[image]
[image]

### Implementation

Ivan Kuckir shares some [fast Gaussian blur algorithms](http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html).

Comment: There's HTML standard telling you how to do `box-shadow` step by step. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#when-shadows-are-drawn