# Checkboxes not displaying Chrome - Work in other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox

I'm not sure what is going on. There should be a checkbox to the left of "Remember Me" and two test ones at the bottom for I have a bike, I have a car. They display in Firefox but not in Chrome. I believe I have a CSS problem but can't find it? Can anyone please help?

http://www.cloudtute.com/auth

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This line in your CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

In the style rule for `input, button, select, textarea` is breaking things for you.

Comment: Thank you both. I have removed that line but it still doesn't show up. Any further ideas - or have I made another mistake?

Comment: Are you very sure that you have removed that line? When I check your website, I can see that it is still there, and as soon as I turn it off, your checkboxes appear..

Comment: Thank you - it turns out the CSS was not uploading correctly.

Answer (score 40):

I am answering on a broader level to those that are running into this issue of checkboxes not showing up in Chrome. And were directed here by google. You may also have this problem in Safari since both are currently using [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).

We ran into this issue on our own website where the checkboxes and radio inputs were not displaying properly. But fixed it by adding this to our CSS.

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
  -webkit-appearance:checkbox;
}
```

Now it works fine.

[image: success]

As you can see, another developer had added `-webkit-appearance: none;` just like in your case. In our case it was because I had started with a theme.

But to make absolutely sure that the inputs show up, it is safe to just declare those rules in your CSS. In this page I placed the styles in the `<style>` tag (which I don't recommend) but I took the screenshot when I was still testing. The better practice would be to remove the conflicting styles and add styles in the appropriate folder.

Additional Resources:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/
https://davidwalsh.name/webkit-appearance
[What is WebKit and how is it related to CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css)
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Answer (score 5):

You have defined the style rule:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

defined for `input, button, select, textarea`, you have to remove it and will work.

You have also a JS error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: containerz is not defined`, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you give width 0px to a checkbox in Firefox, you'll be able to see it but if you open the same code in Chrome, the checkbox will be invisible.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped.. width: 0px was my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the definition of width and height of the checkbox. I had the same error, but I noticed that I had already put small value of width and height of the checkbox, so I removed these properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
When I disabled Ad-Block extension it worked!

Then I added an exception to this site in Ad-Block.

Comment: This might be better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of checkbox to true worked for me

```
value="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason removing this line `height: 100%` from my CSS solved the problem. The checkbox was under a table's `td` element.

So I made this rule just to avoid that single case:

```
table td > input:not([type='checkbox']) {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: block;
}
```

it simply solved my issue

Comment: adding why you did this may be helpful to future users

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by removing the `form-control` class from my checkbox