# Check box checked property doesn't change in Chrome or Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: html, checkbox, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

Suppose you have a check box, which is checked. In Chrome or Firefox, when you click inspect element, in the HTML you will see:

```
<input checked="checked" class="some-class" id="some-id" name="some-name" type="checkbox" value="some-value">
```

I expect, that when I click on the check box and uncheck it, the html will change and the `checked` property will disappear:

```
<input class="some-class" id="some-id" name="some-name" type="checkbox" value="some-value">
```

However, that's not the case. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkboxes not displaying Chrome - Work in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632955/checkboxes-not-displaying-chrome-work-in-other-browsers)

Comment: When you inspect in Chrome the default is to show "styles" for that element. But if you click "properties" to the right you can scroll down and see the status of "checked" and other properties such as "disabled" and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is just the default property defined by the HTML `attribute` of the element when loaded. When unchecked, its the `DOM property` that is whats actually toggled. Which is why the *attribute* does not seem to change.

This follow code outputs the current DOM `checked` property to the console:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    console.log($(this)[0].checked);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2u1bxj8/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think this is best explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/1836143 In particular the Update.