# using webkit-transform rotate in firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, webkit-transform

Hi all I have the following code

```
$('#dialOuter, #dialOuterButtons').css({"-webkit-transform": 'rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ('+rotDeg+'deg)','-webkit-transition': "all 2s ease-in-out",'-webkit-transition-delay':"0.0s"});
```

works fine in Chrome but no other browswers, can anyone tell me how to get it to work in FF, IE etc

tjamls

Comment: That isn't surprising, because Webkit is a rendering engine used in Chrome but not Firefox or IE (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css). To get your transformations to work in other browsers, you'll have to use different vendor prefixes.

Comment: Here's an article showing how you can get your transformations to work on other browsers: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html