# How do you prevent a background image from being zoomed in when it displays as the background for your page?

Tags: html, css

I would like for the background image I'm using for my body tag to cover the entire background without a being zoomed in on one particular part of the image. In other words, I want the image to display as the background as the full picture, not cut off anywhere. Here is the CSS for my current body tag with the image:

```
body {
    background-image: url("weather-background.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not cut off anywhere"? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymspt3fb/) of the css you provided, and the background image is not cut off, though it resizes based on width size.

Comment: My image covers the entire page as expected, but it is zoomed in more toward the top of the picture and doesn't show the full picture basically. The bottom is cut off. I would like the background to show the entire picture. Do you know how to make it fit the background exactly so that 100% of the image is shown?

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;` will force your background image to fit its container element, but it may stretch or distort in unintended ways.

Answer (score 0):

To get image cover background, you can do the following:

```
body {
    background: url(weather-background.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a working [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qanotewalo/edit?html,css,output) example with the following [output](https://output.jsbin.com/qanotewalo).
You can go through [css tricks - perfect full page background image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) for more examples and methods.

Comment: In order to use webkit, do I need to install anything via npm or require anything via script tag?

Comment: No you don't. [Webkit](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/WebKit) is simply a rendering engine that draws the html/css of a webpage in Chrome and Safari. And the css-prefix becomes `-webkit`. Similarly we have `-moz` for firefox, `-o` for opera, and `-msie` for IE, with each browser having their own rendering engine. So when you include all variations (ie. -webkit, -moz, -o etc), you allow the specified property to work across browsers better. Checkout [what is webkit, and how is it related to css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on another website and the client has requested parallax to be used. Here are some CSS properties that I believe could be used to resolve your problem:

```
body {
    background-image: url('wherever');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
{
```

Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So this was what worked for me:

```
body {
    background-image: url("weather-background.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

and then I gave my body tag a class of "contentContainer" and added this jQuery method:

```
$(".contentContainer").css("min-height", $(window).height());
```