# Clip path polygon css in not working in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: html, css, polygon

I wan to cut image from right bottom and it is done but its not working in some browser. Is there any way to do this?

---

**NOTE:**

> Hover effect is necessary.

---

Here is the code.

```css
.clip>a>img{
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 73% 100%);
}
.clip>a>img:hover{
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>


<body>
<div class="clip">
<a href="#">
<img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In short: it doesn't work there because you are using CSS properties that don't belong to their (Firefox's and IE's) rendering engine.

Look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css) to see an informative discussion about it.
The gist is: webkit is an Opera rendering engine, and it works in chrome as well because chrome's rendering engine (Gecko) is based on webkit.

From looking at [this css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) it seems that to get the best support you should add another css rule without the -webkit-, but **it would still not have support across all browsers** (look at the final paragraph with the browser-support summary in the post):

```
.clip>a>img{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 73% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 73% 100%);
}
.clip>a>img:hover{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

Just to reiterate: this will **not** fix your problem with IE and Firefox, as they just don't support the clip-path property yet. You can [see the browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

#### Possible solution

Apart from not doing any clipping in IE and Firefox, you can cut rectangular shape as a fallback in IE and FIrefox - for that you can use the deprecated

```
clip: rect(10px, 20px, 30px, 40px);
```

Look in the post I linked above - it's the first thing there. As he writes there- it's limited (the image has to be absolutely positioned and you can only use it for rectangles, but it is basically supported by all browsers so it's a good fall-back). So if you can get a fallback-design from that it's worth knowing.