# What type of code is -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm teaching myself how to code responsive web pages for work and am woefully behind in some areas. Please be patient with me. I taught myself HTML back in the 90s and picked up some CSS several years ago but haven't gotten much beyond that.

The code itself (anything with -webkit-text-) keeps it from being recognized when I perform a search so I haven't been able to find out what this is from, what it's doing, and how I can make use of it. I have many other questions but for all I know, finding out what this is will help me answer them myself.

Comment: For what `-webkit-` is, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css). For what `text-size-adjust` is, check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust).

Comment: Thanks! At least now I know where to go to learn about it.

Comment: Honestly, I just did a Google search for them. It likely wasn't working for you when you tried searching because Google omits words with `-` infront of them from its search results (searching `apples -oranges` tells Google "search for results about `apples` but remove results about `oranges`"). To get it to not omit them you need to escape the `-` with a \ (`\-webkit-text-size-adjust`). Useful to know for the future.