# Flipping animation behaving very differently in other browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-transforms

I am currently working on making a flipping animation on some divs.

However, I have found that it works incorrectly and differently in every browser that I have tried. Only Edge works the way that I want.

I want clicking the "flip" text to flip over in order to show the `.flipping-view-back` div, and hide the `.flipping-view-front` div. Additionally, the toolbar with `position:fixed` on the back div should be fixed at the top of the page even when scrolling.

In reality, this is only working in some browsers.

On Edge:  This is working exactly how I want it to. [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1St3PH65qG7a5Tt7ILY8TnhKfWIGo_Ik4/view?usp=sharing)

On Chrome: The front div flips over, but there is no back div visible behind it. The back div only pops in once the rotation transition has fully completed. Strangely, scrolling at any time during the flip will also trigger the back div to pop in. Also, scrolling down moves the fixed div out of sight. [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/171ky4fjWkQXTjyeRxie0kYG9d8lQWtdi/view?usp=sharing)

On iOS Safari: This flips correctly, but scrolling down moves the fixed div out of sight. [Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9pGsXEYcBB_RW5HZThxWC1INUQzclhvWGJpc3E1cG5EU3Ew)

In all these videos, I clicked on the flip text and waited for the animation to finish. Then I scrolled down.

**How can I make the flip animation correct and keep the fixed div at the top in all browsers?**

```js
var currView = 0;
const rotatingViewElem = document.querySelector(".main");
const VIEW_FEED = 0;
const VIEW_FLIPPING_SEND = 1;

var viewFeedElem = document.querySelector(".view-positioner.feed");
var viewCreateElem = document.querySelector(".view-positioner.create");
var viewSelectRecipientsElem = document.querySelector(".view-positioner.select-recipients");
var viewFlippingSendElem = document.querySelector(".view-positioner.flipping-send");
var viewsList = [viewFlippingSendElem];

function flipView(isGoForward) {
    var flippingElem = viewsList[currView];
    var globalRotate;

    if (isGoForward) {
        globalRotate = "rotateY(180deg)";//flip around
    } else {
        globalRotate = "rotateY(0deg)";
    }
    flippingElem.style.transform = globalRotate;

}

document.querySelector(".create-send-button").addEventListener("click", function (e) { flipView(true) })
```

```css
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.main{
    perspective: 2000px;
    height:100%;
}
.flipping-view-wrapper{
    
    transform: rotateY(0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 5.5s;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}
.view{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    padding-top:1px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: calc(100% - 1px);
    width:100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.view-positioner{

    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.flipping-view-front{
    background-color: pink;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipping-view-back{
    background-color: green;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.create-send-button{
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* begin top toolbar */
.top-toolbar{
    position:fixed;
    
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:55px;
    background:#FFFB00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body class="lightblue">
<div class="main">

 <div class="view-positioner flipping-send flipping-view-wrapper lightblue ">
  <div class="view-positioner view create flipping-view-front">

   <div class="create-inputs center">


    <div class="create-send-button" style="font-size: 50px;">
     flip to the backside this is long so you can see
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-positioner view select-recipients lightblue flipping-view-back">
   <div class="top-toolbar">
    fixed
   </div>
   <div style="width:10px">Long text a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could have something to do with the browsers itself, maybe look into -webkit. There are webkits for different browser so you might need to use multiple webkits for different browsers

[What is WebKit and how is it related to CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css)

That post might give you some more info

Comment: I've already tried using browser prefixes for the CSS. There is no change.